# Undesired Gradient Shading

Tags: shaders

I am getting this undesired style of shading which gives a high contrast gradient across panels on a mesh object and even shows up in solid viewpoint mode:

[image]

What I'd like is a much flatter shading style, like it is on other objects in the same project, like this:

[image]

Not sure what is happening to create the undesired shading, because the object appears to be setup and lit exactly the same as other objects within the project. Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happenning because you have *smooth* shading applied, to solve that you have to give your model *'Edge Split'* Modifier.